# Spring error including static resources

Tags: css, spring-mvc, resources

I have an error including static resources in my spring mvc project.
My css is in `/webapp/resources/css`.

I have the following lines in my spring dispatcher servlet:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I include it in my jsp file like this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/mycompany.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

The problem is that it's working only if my URL is like:
`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/firstLevel`

But if my URL is like this it's not working:
`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/firstLevel/secondLevel`

If I open the console I can see an error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"

in `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/firstLevel/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js`

Because I think it has to find it in:
`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js`

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
(I can upload some other files if needed)

Thank you

Comment: Looks like this questions answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041961/spring-mvc-static-resources-partially-work?rq=1

Comment: I use like this `<link
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and works fine for any URL