# Error in Admin Panel: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, css, hibernate, spring-mvc, bower

I am creating simple Admin Panel with Spring MVC 4.1.6.RELEASE.

I have problem - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). I does not understand. Where is wrong ?

[image: picture index.jsp]

I have following files.
structure file web :

- assets

  -- bower_components

  -- css

  -- js

  -- image
- WEB-INF

  -- applicationContext.xml

  -- dispatcher_servlet.xml

  -- index.jsp

index.jsp

```
<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<link href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="assets/bower_components/bootbox/boot.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bower_components/bootbox/bootbox.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bower_components/bootbox/bootbox.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath*:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringExamples</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

hibenate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
      jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/employee
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      org.postgresql.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">
      postgres
    </property>
    <property name="connection.password">
      1001
    </property>
    <mapping class="com.Model.Employee"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: If you have a problem, you need to explain what it is and what you've tried to fix it, not just post your code and error message and hope for the best

Comment: I guess my error is
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>  doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question with that information - you'll get much more responses if you can show you've done your research, and have provided as much information as you can

Comment: Please update your question with what is not found. Also why do you have both minified and uncompressed file????

Comment: Also please look for similar questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252756/spring-error-including-static-resources#comment58218622_35252756 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041961/spring-mvc-static-resources-partially-work?rq=1